# Sort query output on taxonomy term archive by post type using pre_get_posts

Tags: order, post-type, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I'm using `pre_get_posts` to adjust the main query of the taxonomy term archive.

What I would like to accomplish is that the output is listed by `post_type`. I have a total of 4 post types and I want to order them as profile, page, post, letter.

I have tried already a few different `order_by` parameters, but no luck yet in getting it right.

I already have come a bit further by adding a `posts_groupby` filter (and removing it again after the query) and although the output is now indeed per `post_type`, it still is not in the desired order.

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'woo_taxonomy_posttype_filter' );
function so_groupby_cpt( $groupby ) {
    if ( preg_match( "/(|[ ,.])id(|[ ,])/i", $groupby ) )
        $groupby = 'post_type';
    return $groupby;
}

function woo_taxonomy_posttype_filter( $query ) {

global $wp_query;

if ( $query->is_tax && ! is_admin() ) {

add_filter( 'posts_groupby', 'so_groupby_cpt' );

// ORDER BY TITLE
$query->set('orderby','menu_order title');
$query->set('order','ASC');
$query->set('posts_per_page','8');

$query->parse_query();

remove_filter( 'posts_groupby', 'so_groupby_cpt' );
}

return $query;

}
```

Is this at all possible or am I asking for the impossible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/87226/6035).

Group by isn't what you want. WordPress, by default, groups by post ID to eliminate duplicate posts from the list. Since you'll need to group by ID and post_type, there will always be only a single combination of post_type and ID (your group by will do nothing, in other words).

Instead of hooking into `post_groupby` use `posts_orderby`. And you add an order by post type, even getting really granular with a SQL `FIELD` function:

```
<?php
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'wpse87578_posts_orderby', 10, 2);
function wpse87578_posts_orderby($orderby, $query)
{
    global $wpdb;

    if (is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query() || !is_tax()) {
        return $orderby;
    }

    $new = "FIELD({$wpdb->posts}.post_type, 'profile', 'page', 'post', 'letter') ASC";

    if ($orderby) {
        $orderby = $new . ', ' . $orderby;
    } else {
        $orderby = $new;
    }

    return $orderby;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your input @chrisguitarguy, but I am afraid that I don't entirely understand. If I replace my filter with yours, nothing changes, same output as I had already remains. What am I missing?

Comment: btw checking the link you gave me now...

Comment: nah, can't get it to work...

Comment: have decided that I will stick with my original `groupby` filter, because at least then the posts are actually grouped by type. Not in the exact order I want them to be, but better than the alternative